# What is the measurement noise in Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

With sampling time $T$, and a continuous measuring model:

$$y(t)=Cx(t)+v(t)$$
$$v(t)\sim N(0,R_c)$$

the discrete version is:

$$y_k=Cx_k+v_k$$
$$v_k\sim N(0,R)$$

where

$$R=\frac{R_c}{T}$$

Now suppose I have a noisy sensor. I took 100 measurements and found that the standard deviation is $\sigma$.

Is $R=\sigma^2$ or $R_c=\sigma^2$?

If $R=\sigma^2$ then does it mean that $R_c$ depends on how fast I took those 100 measurements? If I run the Kalman filter at a rate different from when I took those 100 measurements, will $R$ be different?

If $R_c=\sigma^2$ then I have to divide by $T$ when implementing the Kalman filter. $R$ changes with how quickly I run the Kalman filter loop. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're talking about "taking 100 measurements", you're working with discrete measurements. In the continuous version of the Kalman Filter, measurements are continuously fed back into the system. So $R = \sigma^2$, not $R_c = \sigma^2$.

$R$ will be dependent on how fast you take the measurements. Noise is entering the sensor at some rate, and so each individual measurement will have less noise if you sample more frequently.

Comment: @takfuruya: The noise is measured using $y(t) = C x(t) + \epsilon_t$ so it's measured with respect to the fitted model by estimating $\epsilon_t$. Initializing the noise is a different story where you would need some kind of apriori estimate. ( like a prior ).